# How can I see which of my questions were downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I prefer to ask questions that are clear and useful to others. So if any of my questions are downvoted, I'd like to know which one, so I can either correct the question or not ask similar questions in the future.

I couldn't find a way to find downvoted questions. I can see downvotes in the aggregate summary in my account, but not in the individual questions.

Note: of course, if the question has more downvotes than upvotes, then I can tell from the fact that it has negative total votes. I'm talking about cases when the question has, say, 1 upvote and 1 downvote.

Note: I'm not interested in who downvoted, for obvious reasons. Just which questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the little envelope icon at the top of the page, to the left of your name (on Stack Overflow, not here).  Choose a time range ("yesterday", "last week", "last month", ...) Every question or answer with a -2 next to it is a downvote (-4 is two downvotes, etc).

Only the top 5 posts per time period show up, though. You can also look at your [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), which will show *all* upvotes and downvotes since you created your account, but it'll only show you the post ID - you'll have to translate that to an actual question or answer yourself.

Comment: It seems that all upvotes and downvotes within 1 day are combined. So none of my questions shows a negative number (either in the recent activity or the reputation audit). Since every question got more upvotes than downvotes, the downvote info is lost. While you might say then it doesn't matter, I would like to understand what questions people have problems with.

Comment: @max: hadn't noticed that. Does the reputation audit help?

Comment: If the combined number for questions is not divisible by 5, there has been downvotes. For answers, usually 10 is the divisor, unless it has been accepted (then it is 5). Yet a multiple of 5 downvotes can't be seen like that. That way you should be able to pinpoint most of the downvotes.

Comment: +1 reputation audit - would never have discovered it. But it does combine all activity in one day, so wouldn't show the downvotes. Also, somehow it doesnt show me my own downvotes??

Comment: @max: The audit *does* show my own downvotes, and *doesn't* combine all activity in one day. Don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Possibly because the view is different when you have higher reputation?

Comment: @max: Nope, I verified it on a site on which I have low reputation. I see my downvotes. Care to post a snippet of your audit, and point out where it's wrong?

Comment: 2   3854047 (5)
 2   3854047 (5)
 1   3854178 (2)
-- 2010-10-04 rep +12   = 293        
 2   3854047 (5)
 1   3860102 (2)
 2   3860469 (5)
-- 2010-10-05 rep +12   = 305       at the same time I know I downvoted a couple questions, and I also got one downvote myself.

Comment: @max: I can tell that you've only downvoted one question on SO since you opened your account (http://stackoverflow.com/users/336527/max). Is it possible that the other questions were deleted? Any deleted questions will disappear, entirely, from any report.

Comment: Possibly.. but even that one downvote doesn't show up. Thank you though, I get the idea of how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have over 1000 reputation you can click on the number and it will show a breakdown of up and downvotes.

You can get around the rep points restriction by using the API. Example:
http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/66638/

API docs available [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help).

Comment: +1 for min reputation info